# Auto Count amount with Syntax Error

Tags: php

Okay, so I have a script that looks like the following:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {

     $photo + ++$i =$pwinty->addPhoto($order, $_SESSION['size'][$id], $row['source'], $quantity, "ShrinkToFit");
}
```

Basically I have a variable `i` that starts out at `0` and increases each time a new `$photo` is added to the "list" if you may. So basically the above needs to turn into:

```
$photo1 = ...
$photo2 = ...
$photo3 = ...
```

Right now as the `$photo` line sets now. When the script runs I receive the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' ...
```

I am guessing I need to concatenate this line together, But i'm not sure. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: just curious to know why yo want to create separate variable ? You can use array instead and that would be better approach thought

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It should be like that:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {

     $photo = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, $_SESSION['size'][$id], $row['source'], $quantity, "ShrinkToFit");
$i++;
}
```

Comment: `$i` makes no sense here, and what if `$_SESSION['cart']` is `empty` then `$photo` will give `undefined notice` if used further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$i=1;
$ph='photo';
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
   $photo=$ph.$i;// will give 'photo1' at first
   // $photo1=...
   $$photo =$pwinty->addPhoto($order, $_SESSION['size'][$id], $row['source'], $quantity, "ShrinkToFit");
   echo $$photo; // echo $photo1
   $i++;
}
```

You can `create array` of each variable which can be easily accessible like,

```
$photo=array();
$i=0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
     $photo['photo'][$i++]=$pwinty->addPhoto($order, $_SESSION['size'][$id], $row['source'], $quantity, "ShrinkToFit");
}
print_r($photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

How what you really attempted to do is done, but beware it's really bad practice:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
    ${'photo'.++$i} = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, $_SESSION['size'][$id], $row['source'], $quantity, "ShrinkToFit");
}
// how to output a photo:
if(isset($photo0)){
    echo $photo0;
}
```

This is bad practice, because it creates a lot of variables and is much less inefficient. You should be using arrays.

Should be like this:

```
$photo = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $quantity) {
    $photo[++$i] = $pwinty->addPhoto($order, $_SESSION['size'][$id], $row['source'], $quantity, "ShrinkToFit");
}
// for checking the content of the $photo array:
echo '<pre>';
print_r($photo);
echo '</pre>';
// example of how to access data from the array, where 0 is the first thing that got added, if anything was added:
if(isset($photo[0])){
    echo $photo[0];
}
// traverse the entire array:
foreach($photo AS $id => $p){
    echo 'id: '.$id.', photo: '.$p;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This :

```
$photo + ++$i =
```

is illegal on the left side of assignment as it does ot make sense.

Remove **++$i** and move to the next line

**Update:**

Try to execute this:

```
<?php $photo + ++$i = 3; ?>
```

and you'll get the same syntax error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\PHP\test.php on line 2

Comment: Hey guys - what the duck? OP is asking why he has syntax error. This **<?php $photo + ++$i = 3; ?>** is causing a syntax error - try yourself and don't downvote or explain what is wrong about my answer.